# Fotorama replace images by another

Tags: javascript, fotorama

hello!

i don't know why but i couldn't do the subject

here is my initialization code and it works absolutely fine

```
var drawRootList = function (folders) {
    img = "";
    if (folders.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
            img += "<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/free-folder/256/folder-images-icon.png' data-caption='" + folders[i] + "' >";
        }
    }
    $('.fotorama').html(img).fotorama();
    bindListeners();
}
```

when i'm trying to get another images instead i'm using it

```
var drawList = function (folders) {
    $('.mycanvas').html('');
    img = "";
    for (i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        if (folders[i].indexOf('.') < 0)
            img += "<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/free-folder/256/folder-images-icon.png' data-caption='" + folders[i] + "' >";
        else
            img += "<img src = '/" + _path + folders[i] + "'>";
    }
    $('.mycanvas').add('div').addClass('fotorama');
    $('.fotorama').html(img).fotorama({
        width: 1000,
        maxwidth: '100%',
        ratio: 16 / 9,
        allowfullscreen: true,
        nav: 'thumbs',
        captions: true,
        keyboard: true,
        click: false,
        swipe: false,
        thumbborderwidth: 2
    });

    bindListeners();
}
```

but it doesn't work

what i'm doing not right?

Comment: in firebug i see that all images were gotten, but DOM structure absolutely in a mess. i feel better solution than mine exists, but just can't find it

Answer (score 0):

i've just solved it finally

i should have used .empty method on 'mycanvas' parent and then build all the structure again and initialize fotorama right in this function

```
var drawList = function (folders) {
    $('.ctl00_ctl41_g_20636042_2bc5_4f6d_ba7e_9ad1a1c76d6b').empty();
    var img = "";
    for (i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        if (folders[i].indexOf('.') < 0)
            img += "<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/free-folder/256/folder-images-icon.png' data-caption='" + folders[i] + "' >";
        else
            img += "<img src = '/" + _path + folders[i] + "'>";
    }
    $('.ctl00_ctl41_g_20636042_2bc5_4f6d_ba7e_9ad1a1c76d6b').html("<div class='mycanvas'></div>");
    $('.mycanvas').html("<div class='fotorama'></div>");
    $('.fotorama').html(img).fotorama({
        width: 1000,
        maxwidth: '100%',
        ratio: 16 / 9,
        allowfullscreen: true,
        nav: 'thumbs',
        captions: true,
        keyboard: true,
        click: false,
        swipe: false,
        thumbborderwidth: 2
    });

    bindListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the solution by [tfiwsrets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197782/tfiwsrets) might work (have not tested it), it is not the best way, since instead of updating just the Fotorama, it needs to delete the Fotorama html element, and re-add it.

What I have found is that you can actually remove the data from the Fotorama object and reinitialise it, as follows:

```js
// the urls to add
let image_urls = ["https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTabby_cat&psig=AOvVaw3MDEtAr8UjBK26A3zWk9l7&ust=1601377715230000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKj7roHbi-wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"];

// format the urls as a data object which can be passed to initialise the fotorama (as seen in the doc)
let data = [];
for (image of images) {
    data.push({img: image});
}

// the fotorama object in question
const fotorama = $('.fotorama');

// remove previous contents of the fotorama
fotorama.removeData();

// reinitialise fotorama with the new data
fotorama.fotorama({
    data: data
});
```